# How to use checkbox to prevent certain outputs from running?

Tags: r, visualization, shiny

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("data", "Select data:",
                     c("Iris" = "iris",
                       "Cars" = "mtcars")),
  #####
  checkboxGroupInput("display", "Fit to data:",
                     c("Yes" = "fit",
                       "No"= "nofit")),
  #####
  plotOutput("myPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  dat <- reactive({
    switch()
  })
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
    dat <- switch(input$data,
                  "iris" = iris,
                  "mtcars" = mtcars)
    plot(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, data = get(input$data))
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have a checkbox that lets the user decide whether or not s/he would like the data to be fit. However, I am not sure how I can implement that into my `server`. Essentially, if the user selects `Yes` in the checkbox, then I would like the program to go through with the `renderPlot`, otherwise, don't bother. Perhaps another `switch` that encloses my `renderPlot`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an switch or if then to your renderPlot() call that relies on the input$display.

```
output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
    if(input$display == 'fit') {
      dat <- switch(input$data,
                  "iris" = iris,
                  "mtcars" = mtcars)
      plot(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, data = get(input$data))
     } else {NULL}
  })
```